Using Typescript Parameters<> utility type with generic function
I have a class that looks like this
class MyTestClass {
  getValue<T>(group: string, defaultVal: T): T {}
}

and am attempting to use the Parameters value to make unit testing this class easier (slightly contrived to make my point)

const argList1: Parameters<MyTestClass['getValue']> = ['group_1', 123];

const service = new MyTestClass();

const testValue1 = service.getValue<number>(...argList1);


This gives the following error on the final line
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)

This tracks, since T isn't defined in the Parameters<> definition.
Is there a way to do this? Feel like I have tried angle brackets in every possible position and nothing takes.
I understand I can just not define T when calling the function which returns an undefined, but then I have to cast it manually and it looks messy.

You can maybe use an instantiation expression as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Problem
Parameters<MyTestClass['getValue']> captures the parameter types of getValue as a tuple, but it does not know the type of T because it’s a generic parameter. Therefore, TypeScript treats T as unknown when using Parameters since there’s no way for it to infer T without explicit type information.
This means that you have to help typescript to infer the correct type here.
You can do this, as you mentioned, by manually casting types for parameters.
Solution Trick
class MyTestClass {
  getValue<T>(group: string, defaultVal: T): T {
    // Assume some logic here that returns T
    return defaultVal;
  }
}

// Wrapper function to call getValue with inferred types
function callGetValueWithInference<T>(
  instance: MyTestClass,
  ...args: Parameters<MyTestClass['getValue']>
): T {
  // TypeScript infers T based on the type of args[1]
  return instance.getValue(...args);
}

// Usage
const service = new MyTestClass();
const argList1: Parameters<MyTestClass['getValue']> = ['group_1', 123];

// TypeScript now correctly infers T as number based on argList1[1]
const testValue1 = callGetValueWithInference(service, ...argList1);
console.log(testValue1); // Outputs: 123

How Does It Work
Original Code:

getValue specifies that T should be number.
Parameters<MyTestClass['getValue']> returns a tuple type [string,
unknown] because TypeScript cannot infer what T is when extracting
the parameters. The generic type T isn’t fixed in this context, so it
defaults to unknown.
When you spread argList1 into service.getValue(...argList1),
argList1[1] is of type unknown, which doesn’t match the expected
number type, causing the TypeScript error.

Wrapper Function:

The helper function callGetValueWithInference doesn’t explicitly
provide the type T when calling getValue.
Instead, it lets TypeScript infer T based on the type of args[1]
(which is 123 in this case). Since 123 is a number, TypeScript infers
T as number.
The helper function works because the generic type T is inferred at
the point where the function is called
(callGetValueWithInference(service, ...argList1)) based on the actual
value (123) passed in argList1.


Still feels as a hack and perhaps is an overkill in most cases, as most will find it easier to do manual type casting. But just so you know there is way to trick TypeScript in such case with inference wrapper

I'm confused. I see unknown, not number in your output. Are you sure this is working? Did you test it?

Let me get a fiddle for you, one sec

https://jsfiddle.net/sksirius/rz4672dx/

@jcalz let me know if I understood the assignment correctly

You should see type number for your input there and no error executing the code

the run time doesn't matter. your types should be fine and i guess as pointed @jcalz they aren't

Yeah, I probably got the question wrong, I believe. Pardon me, I'll dig in further
